# A simple question regarding tags and categories

Tags: categories, tags, navigation

I was wondering if there was an easy way to display posts from a tag from a specific category.  In other words, if I have Category1, Category2, and Category3, and these all have posts with a tag 'topic1' what's the easiest way to display the posts containing tag 'topic1' from only one of the above mentioned categories at a time rather than from the entire site at once.

Am I wrong in assuming this is an easy task?

Comment: Do you want to create a custom page template or are you taling about the default tag.php and category.php templates

Comment: @PieterGoosen I think I'm going to have to create a custom page template.

Answer (score 0):

From your comments, you opted for a custom page template. Based on that, you can simply perform a custom query to retrieve posts that belongs to a certain tag and category

I tend to make use of a [`tax_query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters) using [`WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) when you quering posts from more than one taxonomy. It is more flexible, specially if you need to exclude children from hierarchical taxonomies

You can construct your query as follow

```
$args = array(
   'post_type' => 'post',
   'tax_query' => array(
      'relation' => 'AND',
      array(
         'taxonomy' => 'category',
         'field'    => 'slug',
         'terms'    => 'SLUG OF THE CAT',
      ),
      array(
         'taxonomy' => 'post_tag',
         'field'    => 'slug',
         'terms'    => 'SLUG OF THE TAG',
      ),
   ),
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

You can visit the links provided to learn how to construct your loop using `WP_Query`

Comment: Any progress? To help you out and learn how this site operates, please see [help] and [tour]